# Custom Zod errors in tRPC

Tags: zod, trpc.io

How can I set up tRPC so that when zod throws an error I can handle it instead of tRPC. I have looked everywhere for an answer and I can't find one

Comment: Could you post some code or examples of things you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, I wanted form-level and field-level errors. I was also using SvelteKit instead of Next, so the `onError` method in the other answer on this question did not work for me... nor would it work for anyone not using Nextjs. I had to use vanilla TRPC's [errorFormatter](https://trpc.io/docs/server/error-formatting) method override instead of `onError`.

I found out that Zod had the `flatten()` function, which easily provided form-level and field-level errors. This would help me hook the errors directly into my form and my fields... and could even be integrated into a form framework for automation of validations. (Super handy! Makes you so much more productive)

So because of this, I really wanted to do it the right way... i.e. I wanted to modify the custom errors in the backend, so that my backend would always return a consistent error in case of validation issues. I also wanted some semblance of typesafety in the frontend.

Here's how I approached it.

### Backend

First I defined my types like so.

```js
// backend/src/trpc/types.ts

import { typeToFlattenedError } from "zod";
import type { RuntimeConfig } from '@trpc/server/src/core/internals/config';
import { TRPC_ERROR_CODE_NUMBER } from '@trpc/server/src/rpc';
import { TRPCErrorShape } from '@trpc/server/src/rpc/envelopes';

// Utility type to replace the return type of a function
export type ReplaceReturnType<T extends (...a: any) => any, TNewReturn> = (...a: Parameters<T>) => TNewReturn;

// Flattened zod error
export type FlattenedZodError = typeToFlattenedError<any, string>

// This obscure type is taken from TrpcErrorShape, and extends the data property with "inputValidationError"
export type CustomErrorShape = TRPCErrorShape<
  TRPC_ERROR_CODE_NUMBER,
  Record<string, unknown> & { inputValidationError: FlattenedZodError | null }
>

// This type extends the errorFormatter property with the custom error shape
export type CustomErrorFormatter = ReplaceReturnType<RuntimeConfig<any>['errorFormatter'], CustomErrorShape>;
```

Then I defined my errorFormatter.

```js
// backend/src/trpc/errorFormatter.ts

import { ZodError, } from 'zod';
import { CustomErrorFormatter } from './types';

export const errorFormatter: CustomErrorFormatter = (opts) => {
  const { shape, error } = opts;

  const isInputValidationError = error.code === "BAD_REQUEST" && error.cause instanceof ZodError

  if (isInputValidationError) {
    console.log(error.cause.flatten());
  }

  return {
    ...shape,
    data: {
      ...shape.data,
      inputValidationError: isInputValidationError ? error.cause.flatten() : null
    }
  }
}
```

And then I added it to TRPC like this

```js
// backend/src/trpc/instance.trpc

import { initTRPC } from "@trpc/server";
import { errorFormatter } from "./errorFormatter";

const t = initTRPC.create({
  errorFormatter
});

// router
export const router = t.router;
export const publicProcedure = t.procedure;
```

### Frontend

And I can use it in the frontend like this (in SvelteKit.. but it's pretty much just as easy in whatever frontend framework you're using)

```html
<script lang="ts">
    // frontend/src/lib/auth/LoginForm.svelte
    import type { FlattenedZodError } from 'backend/src/trpc/types';
    import { trpcClient as t } from '$lib/trpc';

    let email: string = '';
    let password: string = '';

    let _formErrors: FlattenedZodError['formErrors'];
    let _fieldErrors: FlattenedZodError['fieldErrors'];

    const doLogin = async () => {
        try {
            const result = await t.user.login.mutate({
                email,
                password
            });

            if (result.token) {
                localStorage.setItem('token', result.token);
                window.location.href = '/';
            }
        } catch (e: any) {
            if (e.data && e.data.inputValidationError != null) {
                // here is where we get the errors
                const { fieldErrors, formErrors } = e.data.inputValidationError as FlattenedZodError;
                _fieldErrors = fieldErrors;
                _formErrors = formErrors;
            } else {
                console.log('Unknown error', e);
            }
        }
    };
</script>

<div class="card bg-base-200">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-title">
            <h1 class="header-2">Login</h1>
        </div>
        {#if _formErrors?.length > 0}
            <div class="alert alert-error flex flex-col gap-2">
                {#each _formErrors as error}
                    <p>{error}</p>
                {/each}
            </div>
        {/if}
        <form on:submit={doLogin} class="flex flex-col gap-4">
            <div>
                <input
                    class={'input input-bordered input-ghost ' + (_fieldErrors?.email ? 'input-error' : '')}
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="Email"
                    bind:value={email}
                />
                {#if _fieldErrors?.email}
                    <div class="text-error flex flex-col gap-0">
                        {#each _fieldErrors.email as error}
                            <p>{error}</p>
                        {/each}
                    </div>
                {/if}
            </div>
            <div>
                <input
                    class={'input input-bordered input-ghost ' +
                        (_fieldErrors?.password ? 'input-error' : '')}
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    bind:value={password}
                />
                {#if _fieldErrors?.password}
                    <div class="text-error flex flex-col gap-2">
                        {#each _fieldErrors.password as error}
                            <p>{error}</p>
                        {/each}
                    </div>
                {/if}
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, such a comprehensive response, TIL Zod errors can be flattened – thank you! <3

Answer (score 0):

https://trpc.io/docs/error-handling#handling-errors

> All errors that occur in a procedure go through the onError method before being sent to the client. Here you can handle or change errors.

Here's a basic example of changing a zod error on server, before it hits client:

```js
onError: ({ error }) => {
    if (error.cause instanceof ZodError) {
        // Returning only first zod error message to client
        error.message = JSON.parse(error.message)[0].message;
    }
}
```